# Questions connecting to swagger endpoint as client from Maven Project

Tags: maven, jwt, swagger, token, endpoint

I am working with a Maven Project that uses Spring and is written in Groovy. This project is also a web application that has it's own UI, servers, environments, and authentications.

I need this application to connect to a swagger api endpoint that has been set up by another team and return the result.

**I don't need to create a new endpoint. I need to connect to one that already exists**

The issue the endpoint requires a token and I am unsure how to go about setting that up.

I found this article that showed running a command line tool for swagger code gen.
https://phauer.com/2015/enriching-restful-services-swagger/

In the client section it shows using the cmd to generate a new maven project. But the issue is I don't want to generate a new maven project because I already have one that exists.

Does any one know another way of the client generating a token from the endpoint?

I'm about to go through the ApiClient documentation because I think that might have the answer but again that is using OAuth2 and the endpoint I am trying to connect I believe uses a JWT and doesn't have a clientid or secretid.

Wondering if anyone has come across this issue and has any advice or pointers to documentation on which dependencies/libraries to look into to be able to do this.

EDIT: I was able to talk to the team and was given a token and header that I can now use to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [configure your Spring application as an OAuth2 client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html) to fetch tokens. You are probably interested in the `client_credentials` flow.

Then, use a REST client to send a request with `Authorization` header set with a token from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`. You might consider using `@FeignClient` or `RestClient` as REST clients, both have tooling to easily set the `Authorization` header with a `Bearer` token. Refer to the documentation of the client you choose.